# Jquery Hide rest of the fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

How do I modify the below code to hide all fields except the ones needed to be shown? Have 20 more fields do not one to name them one by one to hide.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
$('nobr:contains("stuff1")').closest('tr').show();
$('nobr:contains("stuff2")').closest('tr').show();
//Hide the rest of the fields without mentioning their names
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide all the fields using CSS `display:none` and enable the ones you need using JQuery.

Comment: JQuery is not enabling the fields...believe the CSS is blocking all the fields...anyway to get around this? How do I trigger CSS first and then JQuery?

Comment: CSS should always execute first. Place any `<link>` elements above any `<script>` elements in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is wondering what I did...I ended up just hiding each field that needs to hidden.